# nginx blank page/400 bad request for special characters in URL on Confluence 6.2.1

Tags: nginx, confluence

So recently I have been experiencing issue where when accessing URL, like `www.example.com/comfluence/display/TST/<testpage>+test` would show just white blank page and from Chrome console it shows 400 bad request. This started to happen just after upgrading Confluence. Previously on 5.8.5 version there was no such issue. Upgrading to 6.1.1 or 6.2.1 it started ti behave like this.
I am using nginx proxy server and no config has been changed during the upgrade.
The config looks like this

```
location /confluence/ {

    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    error_page 404 @error_404;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 @error_5xx;

    client_max_body_size 100m;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    proxy_read_timeout 900;
    proxy_pass http://Dconfluence/confluence/;

}

  location /synchrony/ {

  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_pass http://Dsynchrony/synchrony/;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
}
```

As per documentation.
I am sure its nginx issue as I can access those pages bypassing it and using private IP.

If anyone could help me on this, I would appreciate it. I have already contacted Atlassian Support and waiting for their reply as well.

Comment: Have you changed anything in your server.xml file after upgrade? ;-)

Comment: Hi Saleh, no, I am using default server.xml just modified to be used with my proxy

Comment: bingo! Add proxyName and ProxyPort in server.xml as well as fix the contexParh :-)

Comment: Hi Saleh,
by saying I have modified server.xml to be used with my proxy I meant that it has already 
`scheme="https" proxyName="example.com" proxyPort="443" secure="true"`
added to Connector as well as contextPath is set to /confluence 
In case it wouldnt, I believe the whole Confluence would not work, but everything works fine except for accessing URLs with those characters, in this case brackets ( < > )

Answer (score 0):

If you only have problem with URLs that contains characters like (`<>`) it might be related to the double encoding. So, I would say check if you have `chunked_transfer_encoding on;` in your Nginx Configuration files or not. If so, remove it and restart your Nginx. Atlassian has a KB about similar behaviour would be good if you take a look at it as well ([here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/strange-encoding-issues-with-nginx-844629392.html)).